# smtp email keeps getting suspended

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

hello i need help i'm learning web devoloper, i used php mailer to send email confimation and the code works but ater a while the email keeps getting suspended when i asked the hostinger support they said its because of bad phpmailer on my configuration on my part  here is a part of the report  he gave me :
From: <>
To:
e-****@********.com
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
Content Rejected
2022-02-07 10:59 AM
Sender ID:
68* * **3
he explaind as follows :
**If you look closely at each report, they all have the same "SENDER ID" which is 68-----3
That "sender ID" is what causes your emails to be marked as SPAM, since the security filter detects it as dangerous, since the "Sender ID" should be shown as an email;**.
he said i should replace the the senders id with my email.
and here is my code for the PHPMailer :

```
                        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    try {
                        //Server settings
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
                        $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
                        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.hostinger.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
                        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
                        $mail->Username   = 'e----@-----.com';                     //SMTP username
                        $mail->Password   = '--------';                               //SMTP password
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
                        $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`


                        $mail->addCustomHeader('Sender ID', 'e-class@imranechaibi.com');
                        //Recipients
                        $mail->setFrom('e----@-------.com', '----------');
                        $mail->addAddress($email, 'E------ team');     //Add a recipient
                        //$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
                        //$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
                        //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                        //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

                        //Attachments
                        //$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
                        //$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

                        //Content
                        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
                        $mail->Subject = $firstname;
                        $mail->Body    = $email."<br>".$msg;
                        //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

                        $mail->send();
                        header('Location: ./index.php');
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        // echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by setting that sender ID header?

Comment: @Synchro i guess yes as thats what he told me i need to do to stop my emails from getting suspeded

Comment: Well, it won't actually do anything: header labels are not permitted to contain spaces, so it may simply be because you're submitting an invalid email message. Try just not setting it. If you want to set the return address for bounces, PHPMailer will handle that for you if you put your email address in the `Sender` property, though it sets that using your `From` address by default, so you probably don't need to touch it.

Comment: ok i got it thank you so much for ur help